# Visual Studio 2008 Performance Profiler Problems with ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio-2008, profiling

I've been trying, and failing, to get VS.NET 2008 to profile an ASP.NET MVC application. When I try and start a profiling session I get a generic server 500 error from VS.NET:

The web site could not be configured correctly; getting ASP.NET process information failed. Requesting 'http://localhost:4750/foo/VSEnterpriseHelper.axd' returned an error: The remote server returned an error: (500) Internal Server Error.

I've tried several things, including:

- ensuring that web.config is writable
- ensuring that there aren't any permissions issues (everything is running as me, I'm an admin, and UAC is off)
- everything mentioned here:
  [500 Error Running Visual Studio ASP.NET Unit Test](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/260432/500-error-running-visual-studio-asp-net-unit-test)

A brand new ASP.NET MVC app (i.e. File | New | Project ) will profile without problem, so I know my machine is capable of profiling such an app.

So, my question here is what are the other common and uncommon things that can prevent VS.NET from starting a profiling session on an ASP.NET app?

Comment: For me the answer was "stop trying to use the VS.NET profiler and use Red-Gate's ANTS profiler instead". I instantly became productive when I changed to ANTS.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you can't get VS.Net profiling to work there are a couple of 3rd party tools that might help. Obviously youy'll need to pay for these though.

ANTS has a free demo here: http://www.red-gate.com/products/ants_memory_profiler/index_v2.htm

JetBrains also have a trace tool that offers profiling (I have not used this but I like their Resharper tool, so I suspect this will be good): http://www.jetbrains.com/profiler/index.html

Comment: ANTS worked first time and has already given me some excellent results. Thanks deadbeef.

Answer (score 4):

In between wrestling with profilers, you can easily get a pretty good picture of what your program is doing from a time perspective by [this method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/375913/what-can-i-use-to-profile-c-code-in-linux/378024#378024). What it reveals is usually a surprise.

Added: I do a fair amount of tuning, and I have a different perspective on these things, such as: wall-clock time is all that matters, individual instructions are more important than functions/methods, call trees & graphs are interesting but nobody knows what they really mean in terms of performance, the demos are all stilted toys like Mandelbrot, and individual samples are where the money's at, not summaries.

For example, tuning a .NET app, it takes a long time starting up. So in that interval, I sample it several times and ask "What is it doing and why?" It is looking up strings by ID in resources (so the strings can be internationalized). Is it necessary? If I look at the particular strings, they are ones that never need to be internationalized. No profiler can tell me this, but samples find it immediately.

Comment: Nice answer. You're right about asumptions - ANTS has pointed out several methods that I didn't think would ever be problematic.

Comment: @Martin: Thanks. I added more explanation of what I mean.

Answer (score 4):

Here is how I got it worked for my ASP.NET site under VS2010

1. Make sure your web.config is writable
2. Create a new performance session and don't add any project to it

Instead add the URL of your website "Target -> right click -> add existing web site"
Make sure to run the web site once so that the IIS process or ASP.NET server process is up and running

1. Right click on your performance session and choose 'Attach', and choose your web server process

Now go to your site and do whatever scenarios, then back to your VS and click stop.

Comment: Great answer.  One suggestion, it is easier to read a response (especially those with ordered lists) if you format the lists as such.  I would do it to show you, but I cannot edit your response.

Answer (score 2):

Not sure if you've seen this:
http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/tfsbuild/thread/8366799f-7bfd-4c80-a5f1-11a57ecfd966/

but it appears to be reporting the same issue you have and there is a response from the MSFT developer who wrote the Profiler tool:)

Comment: Thanks. This looks like it might be useful.

Answer (score 2):

If you have a split configuration setup with external *AppSettings*, this is likely to cause an error like this.

The Visual Studio profiler seems to have a problem identifying that you include your AppConfig settings via

```
<appSettings configSource="App_Config\AppSettings.config" />
```

and that it needs to insert any AppSettings necessary for profiling there instead of  the web.config directly.

In my case, moving the AppSettings back into the web.config fixed the issue.

Comment: Hmmm. That's interesting. I don't have an external AppSettings.config, but I do have lots of other external .config files. I wonder if that's related. +1 for an interesting suggestion.